# Eclipse FindBugs plugin fails with Android project asking for java.rmi.remote

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I'm using **FindBugs plugin 2.0.2.20121210** for eclipse Juno in an Android Project. When it starts fetching bugs it goes ok, but when it ends it shows an error at the Error Log tab that says

```
"The following classes needed for findbugs analysis on project xx were
missing: java.rmi.remote"
```

And it doesn't show any bug, even thought the counter that appears at the progress dialog while it's executing the analysis shows a number of them.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just for the record I managed to answer my question. I had to disable some of the **Detector Configurations** under `Project properties->FindBugs->Detector Configuration`

Comment: Which detectors did you disable?

Comment: Uff, I don't remember. It's a long time since I left Eclipse and move to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I used the command line and disabled the following detectors aka visitors.

```
-chooseVisitors -FindUninitializedGet,-UnreadFields,-FindNullDeref,-BadAppletConstructor,-FindMaskedFields,-DontIgnoreResultOfPutIfAbsent,-ReadOfInstanceFieldInMethodInvokedByConstructorInSuperclass
```