# Findbugs not working in Eclipse for Android project error java.rmi.Remote

Tags: java, android, eclipse, findbugs

When I run Findbugs plugin in eclipse I get the following error in the log

> !ENTRY edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse 2 2 2013-05-01 11:13:13.289
>   !MESSAGE The following classes needed for FindBugs analysis on project
>   android-enterprise-im-client were missing: !SUBENTRY 1
>   edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse 2 0 2013-05-01 11:13:13.289
>   !MESSAGE java.rmi.Remote

I found this post: [Eclipse FindBugs plugin fails with Android project asking for java.rmi.remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935979/eclipse-findbugs-plugin-fails-with-android-project-asking-for-java-rmi-remote) which mentions   "disable some of the Detector Configurations under Project properties->FindBugs->Detector Configuration"

If I disable all the detectors the error goes away but I don't get any warnings either.

My Eclipse version is:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Findbugs Version is: 2.0.2.20121210

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Same Here,Findbugs: 3.0.0.20140706-2cfb468
Eclipse Luna: 4.4.0